Support Needed for Inequality Problem: $\frac{5x+\sqrt8}{\sqrt7}>\frac{x\sqrt{14}-2}{\sqrt2}$
I have some questions in my mind about this question. Can you please help me about that?

$$\frac{5x+\sqrt8}{\sqrt7}>\frac{x\sqrt{14}-2}{\sqrt2}$$
A) $x<\sqrt{2+\sqrt{12}}$
B) $x< \sqrt{2+\sqrt{10}}$
C) $x< \sqrt{2+\sqrt{14}}$
D) $x< \frac{3\sqrt{2+\sqrt{14}}}2$
E) Not in the answers


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Photos and answers updated. I am still wondering the answer

You say you have some questions in mind about the question, what are they?

@JoshThompson I am just searching for answer to check mine

Well, what's the progress you've made so far?

$$\frac{5x\sqrt{8}}{\sqrt{7}}>\frac{x\sqrt{14}-2}{\sqrt{2}}$$
Multiply both sides by $\sqrt{14}$
$$\sqrt{2}(5x+2\sqrt{2})>\sqrt{7}(\sqrt{17}x-2)\\5\sqrt{2}x+4>7\sqrt{2}x-2\sqrt{7}\\-2\sqrt{2}x>2\sqrt{7}-4\\x<\frac{\sqrt{7}}{2}+\frac{2}{\sqrt{2}}\\x<\frac{\sqrt{14}}{2}+\sqrt{2}$$
So the correct answer is E.
